# How can I properly authenticate to use Google Calendar API in my nodejs backend?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

So basically I want to host a very small Nodejs app on a VM on DigitalOcean.
The app reads data from an open website each hour and based on the data I want to create events on my own google calendar. I only need access to my own google calendar.

I tried to simply use an API key but found out that the calendar API does not support the API key anymore. I should use Oauth2. But when I integrate Oauth2 it is more suitable for allowing any google account for my backend and also it requires the user to confirm visually the Oauth2 consent.

To be honest I do not know how I would integrate that into my nodejs app hosted somewhere else. But I also may not understand the basics here so maybe somebody could point me to a good resource?
I just want to retrieve my own calendar data and write to it :(